# How do I automatically set off TNT using Command Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know if there is a way to make it so when a player places a block  of TNT, it immediately fuses, without the use of flint and steel, fire charges, etc.

Please, no mods or plugins.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AesTxQdJR_E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a command block to remotely prime it, just use `/setblock <coordinates> minecraft:redstone_torch` to place a redstone torch next to the TNT (you can replace `minecraft:redstone_torch` with anything that would output a signal like).

Otherwise, if you want TNT to be primed when placed, you could use [/fill](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#fill) replacing TNT with primed TNT, i'm not sure of primed YNY's data value though. To have it keep executing just use [this clock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/129616/30879).

Comment: I know all that stuff that's what the etc. was for but I just want it so when someone places it on the ground in an enclosed room it automatically sets off just using Command Blocks and TNT thats all

Comment: @FireStrike289 missed the command block part, think the edit should do it

Comment: Using /setblock implies that the Command Block knows where the TNT is gonna get places in this I want you to be able to place it wherever you want. Also the room I'm talking about it a 71x71 circular room with a 36 block high dome I have mobGriefing off but the TNT is to kill mobs like a weapon but you need to be able to place it wherever you want

Comment: @FireStrike289 edited adding in method for using `/execute` and `/fill`, though i'm not entirely sure of the results, in theory it should work if you set the xyz/xyz2 values of `/fill` to cover your room

Comment: I'm not sure how to use **/execute** so if you could tell me I guess I can accept your answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: @FireStrike289 just realized you don't need `/execute`, you just need `/fill` to loop which i was given a great clock system, likewise you still use `/fill` to set the xyz/xyz2 values of /fill to cover your room and you replace tnt with primed tnt

Comment: PrimedTNT is an entity and therefore can't be used in setblock or fill. How exactly does the fill method work?

Comment: I've made something so that thrown TNT turns into PrimedTNT, but as for the block, I don't know.

Comment: Primed TNT isn't a block. It's an entity. You can't just replace it.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs this, in the newer versions there are two ways of doing this.

Method 1, Use spawn eggs instead:

```
/give @p mooshroom_spawn_egg{display:{Name:'{"text":"Primed TNT Spawn Egg","color":"red","italic":false}'},EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:tnt",Fuse:0}} 1
```

This spawns a tnt entity with a fuse of 0^

The other would be to have a command block running on repeat with the command:

```
execute as @e[type=tnt] run data merge entity @s {Fuse:0}
```

But this only sets the fuse to 0 once a piece of tnt is lit, which is not what this question was looking for but still could be helpful.