# How can I extend the length of the DaylightCycle on a Java Edition Spigot 1.16.4 Minecraft Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I set up a  Java Edition Spigot 1.16.4 Minecraft Server, and I'd like to figure out how to extend the length of the DayLightCycle. I've looked around on other posts, however, they date back to 1.9 and I don't know how the modern syntax of the old scripts. One used a scoreboard, one simply used a redstone clock, they all varied, yet none of them still work. I'd prefer to find a plugin, as I'm concerned that using vanilla command blocks will generate an unnecessary amount of lag.

Older Posts on the issue:
[Is there a way to slow down the Day/Night cycle?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129607/is-there-a-way-to-slow-down-the-day-night-cycle)

[Can you increase the amount of time in a day?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255899/can-you-increase-the-amount-of-time-in-a-day?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

People in the reviews of [this plug-in](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/variabletime.14573/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=a53d598f4a16d9bae65b22b62d0e1e8036364510-1610605718-0-AbOYVtJbzBP_LSLR4o0eO3_JJwDSkpgsaErJVYv3I93hxkW9yNmaf4uP-l3D_H9h52-bZ3lKCgM1CMsLAhi7pOejaGGWzHLlia0CAMzNau8Xo3msem6n-1O0hxQep0WeckzP3gdg_kVJ4YH9TH-tX8Sod1swy_PIvnNY41bJ-Q8dX-CHtT7_0g-dsbrGVxN62QkQpuvXJ1_MBW4it7EYFPMRffCBkc2bCqh_47Tu3L0LLQ23FKDeW_bhFiWRvJEcLL9wtVehq71saak-7VsegH4A5BoBprMJasJrdnokho0kwrCs2amSwC8fetm5HAIBDa8XaSY-eD3NMkhzMzpksf8) say that it works on 1.16.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to extend it exept using a painfulo way with repeaters and command blocks that would /time set 12 500, then /time set 12 550, etc...
However, I know there are mods that allow you to sync your in game time with the real world time. Maybe there are mods that let you choose how long the day light cycle is...